# Why i am able to go to any route after locahost, and get my homepage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router

I am creating a ReactJs application which fetches pokemon stats, names and pictures using REST API, However, when I try to set up my Route using React Router, I am able to navigate to any of the provided routes, but I am getting the same homepage on whatever I request after localhost:3000/

I have hosted my project on GitHub, please refer for reference "https://github.com/abhinav-anshul/Pokedex-A-collection-of-Pokemons"

To be careful, I deleted my Route.js file from my project structure, to see if I am able to go to any links, and yes I can still visit any links after my localhost:3000/ such as "localhost:3000/doesnotexist", and I still get my homepage, which is "index.js"

// Here is my Route.js file which I deleted, because even at "localhost:3000/pokemon", I got the same page rendered to the screen from "index.js"

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./components/Navbar";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Link, NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import PokemonDetails from "./components/PokemonDetails";

const Route = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={index} />
      <Route path="/pokemon" component={PokemonDetails} />
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
);

export default Route;
```

Comment: What is in that index component, how do you render the `Route` object that you are exporting. it may be a naming issue, try renaming your component something other than Route, because Route is already defined. Also what is in your index component

Comment: The index component is my homepage, where I have rendered other components like <Navbar />, <pokemonList />, <pokemonDetails />. when i type "localhost:3000" it renders my home screen AS EXPECTED but even when I try to type random routes, i am still getting the same homepage without any error like "localhost:3000/randompage"

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use "exact path" for homepage.

```
<Route exact path="/" component={index} />
```

Comment: forgot to add in the code, I tried but no luck, still having the same issue

Comment: I did not see you imported "index" component. import it first.

Comment: I have deleted this file, yet still able to browse any route like "localhost:3000/doesnotexist" and it shows up exactly what is showing in my "localhost:3000" which is the home page

Comment: And another thing, index.js is by deafult loaded for react. you have to put <route exact path="/" component={route}> or somthing in index file. if you try to edit route.js and hope to get result in index, you need to edit your index file. i hope it helps you.

Comment: No, I want index.js file to be rendered on the screen for "/" . The issue is not with this Route.js but something else, as i have deleted this file from my project, but still able to navigate to any route, and get the same homepage

Comment: so what is the problem actually? if you deleted the file, you should get a 404 back, and if you add a 404 page in your project, it would not redirect you to the homepage anymore. then it will redirect you to the 404 page.

Comment: That is the issue, even if I deleted the file, I am not seeing any error, but the same homepage on whatever non-existent route I type in

Comment: add a 404 page. it will be gone

Comment: No sorry, it is not rendering any other component on any routes, just homepage, adding a 404 page will still render homepage(that is my index.js component)